# How to write a tuple of tuples to a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have a tuple of tuples

```
import csv
A = (('Max', 3 ,' M'),('bob',5,'M'),('jane',6,'F'))
result = open("newfile.csv",'wb')
writer = csv.writer(result, dialect = 'excel')
writer.writerow(A)
result.close
```

This writes a CSV file with rows with A[0], A[1] and A[2] . 
What i want is a row with name, age and gender , which has the corresponding values .

Comment: you want one row with 3 columns, each for name, age and gender, and you're getting one column with all three inside?

Answer (score 11):

Write all rows at once:

```
writer.writerows(A)
```

instead of

```
writer.writerow(A)
```

File newfile.csv looks now like this:

```
Max,3, M
bob,5,M
jane,6,F
```

Also, add `()` to your last line, it is a function call: `result.close()`.

If you are on Python 2.6 or newer, you can use this form:

```
import csv
A = (('Max', 3, 'M'),('bob', 5, 'M'),('jane', 6, 'F'))
with open('newfile.csv', 'wb') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(A)
```

Comment: Equivalently, `for row in A: writer.writerow(A)`. But since you're constructing `A` upfront you might as well use `writerows`.

Comment: +1 I was doing it like `csv.writer(f).writerows([x for x in a])` I'm off to rtfm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you fully but I think this will help :

```
    print >>f, "\n".join([",".join(x) for x in A]);
```

Comment: Profit from the `csv`, don't reinvent the wheel with this construct (imagine one field being "Max,Happy" would break your CSV file)

Comment: Is csv pre-installed with python?

Comment: it belongs to the Python Standard Library http://docs.python.org/library/fileformats.html

Comment: CSV is inbuilt in Python 2.3 onwards