# Python how can i sort a csv file by the column id

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a large csv file in the format e.g.

```
POBOX,DEPT,ORGNAME,SUBBNAME,BUILDING,BNUM,STREET,LOCALITY,TOWN,COUNTY,POSTCODE,ID
,,,,,20,A STREET,,EXETER,DEVON,EX1 2SP,10013036001
,,,FLAT 0,,100,ALPHO ROAD,,EXETER,DEVON,EX2 8JD,10013036004
,,,JANB,,100,ALPHO ROAD,,EXETER,DEVON,EX2 8HZ,10013036003
,,,,,2A,BLACKHALL ROAD,,EXETER,DEVON,EX4 4HE,
,,,,,300,FOR STREET,HEAVITREE,EXETER,DEVON,EX1 2QN,
```

I have manually sorted this file by the column ID (the last column) in Excel and saved it.
I would like to write a python method to open the file and sort it by the column id and then write it back to the file, save it.
Is this possible?

Riaz

Comment: How're you reading in the data? If you're reading it in as a two dimensional array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099669/python-sort-multidimensional-array-based-on-2nd-element-of-subarray

Comment: The file is being read from a method, my colleague has written some code to compare the data between 2 files.  The method is  def diff_reports(): c = FileComparator([r"C:\QA\output\Excel sorted\file11.csv",
                        r"C:\QA\output\Excel sorted\file12.csv"],
                       11, r"C:\QA\gazdb ABP output\Excel sorted\errs_5.csv")
    c.compare(0)

Comment: I would like to have the file sorted by ID column before i call the method which compares the data

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I am reading up on this to try and do it https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
array = csv.reader(open('1.csv','r'))
a = list(array)[:] # for a[0] - save first line
s_array = [a[0]] + sorted(a[1:], key=lambda x: x[-1])
csv.writer(open('2.csv', 'wb'), dialect='excel').writerows(s_array)
```

special thanks to:

[Python tuples sorting based on last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829300/python-tuples-sorting-based-on-last-element)

[How to write a tuple of tuples to a CSV file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687568/how-to-write-a-tuple-of-tuples-to-a-csv-file-using-python)

[Converting a csv file into a list of tuples with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776370/converting-a-csv-file-into-a-list-of-tuples-with-python)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It is sorting the files but the records that don't have a value in the ID column are appearing first.  I would like the records that do have an ID value to appear first and in sorted order

Comment: E.g. record without an id value: ,,,,,201,BLACKHALL ROAD,,EXETER,DEVON,EX4 4HE,

Comment: E.g. record with an id value: ,,,,,28,ALPHA STREET,,EXETER,DEVON,EX1 2SP,10013036001

Comment: I think I have got it.  I changed key=lambda x: x[-1]) to key=lambda x: x[1])

Comment: I got excited to quick.  It hasn't sorted it for the rows which has an ID value to appear at the top.  The records with a blank ID are appearing at the top.  I would like it for the records that do have an ID value to appear at the top

Comment: try this hack: 
s_array = [a[0]] +  sorted(a[1:], key=lambda x: x[-1] if x[-1] else '~'). Because
'~' is penultimate symbol in ascii table